# Pairs of irreducible fractions that add up to a given irreducible fraction

Tags: fractions, integer-partitions, rational-numbers

Given the irreducible fraction $\frac a b$, with $a, b \in \mathbb N$, what is the expression that enumerates all the irreducible fractions of integers that add up to $\frac a b$? Namely, an expression (in terms of $a$ and $b$) for all the $\frac c d$ and $\frac e f$, with $c,d,e,f \in \mathbb N$, such that $\frac c d + \frac e f = \frac a b$.

Comment: Stern-Brocot tree and (related) Farey sequence are the answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Every couple of fractions $c/a$ and $d/b$ in the Stern-Brocot tree  can be represented (in the inverse notation according to *Concrete Mathematics*) by the matrix 
${\bf M} = \left\| {\,\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   a & b  \\
   c & d  \\
\end{array}\,} \right\|$, where, iff the fractions are the generators of another fraction in the tree, then the determinant of the matrix $=1$, so that:
$$
a\,d - c\,b = 1\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \frac{1}{{a\,b}} + \frac{c}{a} = \frac{d}{b}\,\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \frac{c}{a} < \frac{d}{b} \\ 
 \frac{1}{{a\,c}} + \,\frac{b}{a} = \frac{d}{c}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \frac{b}{a} < \frac{d}{c} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$
So, given $d/b$, it will be equal to a lower-value (left-side)  "co-parent"fraction $c/a$ (determinant $= 1$) plus $1/(ab)$.
Iterating along the tree you get infinite couples, unless you fix a limit on the $1/(ab)$ term.
If that is the case, that is that you fix a maximum denominator, than you may work better on the Farey sequences, arranged on a tree.

---

Another, geometrical, approach.
Suppose you may fix a upper limit (say $d$) to the denominator of the fractions that shall sum to $a/b$, 
since otherwise their number is infinite, as already seen.
Then, the solutions in the 1st quadrant (octant) to the diophantine linear equation
$$
\frac{x}{d} + \frac{y}{d} = \frac{a}{b}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad x + y = \frac{a}{b}d\quad \left| {\;{\rm integers}\;a,b,d,x,y} \right.
$$
will provide all the reduced and un-reduced fractions with denominator $d$.
Their number will clearly be null if $d$ is not a multiple of $b$, 
otherwise it will be equal to $n=ad/b+1$  including the null one ($\left\lceil {n\backslash 2} \right\rceil $).

When we consider the fractions reduced, they will span all the fractions with denominators being a divisor of $d$
$$
\frac{{x_{\,k} }}{{m_k }}\quad \left| \begin{array}{l}
 \;m_k \backslash d \\ 
 \;b\backslash d \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$

That is where the connection with Farey sequences comes in.

Now you can plan various choices for $d$, for instance $d=b!$, or $d=b*q!$ …
 '---------

**Examples**

*1st approach)*
Take the fraction $5/8$: the picture shows a portion of the SB tree around it.
[image]
Thus we can write:
$$
{5 \over 8} = \left\{ \matrix{
  {3 \over 5} + {1 \over {40}} = \left( {{4 \over 7} + {1 \over {35}}} \right) + {1 \over {40}} = {4 \over 7} + {3 \over {56}} = \;\left( {{1 \over 2} + {1 \over {14}}} \right) + {3 \over {56}} =  \cdots  \hfill \cr 
  {8 \over {13}} + {1 \over {104}} = \; \cdots  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
Note that the fractions that with $5/8$ will generate a new fraction in the tree (are "co-parents" with $5/8$) are those that are adjacent to it (at its level or lower). In our case we shall choose among those adjacent to the left ($3/5$, $8/13$, and lower levels).

*2nd approach)*
from
$$
{x \over d} + {y \over d} = {5 \over 8}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad x + y = {5 \over 8}d
$$
choosing e.g.
$$
d = 16\;\quad  \Rightarrow \quad x + y = 10
$$
we get
$$
{5 \over 8} = {1 \over {16}} + {9 \over {16}} = {1 \over 8} + {1 \over 2} = {3 \over {16}} + {7 \over {16}} = {1 \over 4} + {3 \over 8} = {5 \over {16}} + {5 \over {16}}
$$
and these are all the fractions with denominator <= 16.

Comment: Could you provide here definitions for parent and co-parent fractions? (couldn't find a decent definition out there...)

Comment: well, actually for what you are considering, the generated mediant is of no use. Forgive,  I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: While the nature of the problem is clearly connected to the SB tree, the answer seems to be posed in terms that keep it distant from a direct solution, at least for the illiterate. May be it would be good to illustrate the first solution with an example. Say, how to generate in practice the pairs that sum up to 5/8, and are not smaller than 1/8, i.e. 1/2 + 1/8 and 1/4 + 3/8.

Comment: For the example above, what would be the assignment? $d = 5$, $b = 8$; now, if $1/(ab) = 1/8$, then $a = 1$, but $c/a = 1/2$, so $a = 2$. We'd find another contradiction for the second example.

Comment: Also, for all rationals of the form $p/q$, with $p>1$, the composition $p/2q + p/2q$ does not comply with the SB-based solution (e.g., $3/5 = 3/10+3/10$ but none of the summands fits the $1/(ab)$ pattern).

Comment: accept your critics, added examples, and made explicit that the deteminant =1 applies to "co-parents" fractions, i.e. those who are the parents of another fraction on the tree, that is that they are adjacent. Hope now is correct and clear.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is simplify your expression:

$$\frac{c}{d} + \frac{e}{f} = \frac{cf + ed}{df} = \frac{a}{b}$$

The numerator and denominator will give you a system of two linear equations. With $a$ and $b$ fixed there are four unknowns $c,d,e,f$. As $4>2$ this means we have infinitely many solutions (as would be expected):

$$a = cf + ed$$
$$b = df$$

Now, with two parameters $T, S \in \mathbb R$ and substituting $c = T, d = S$ (for example):

$$a = Tf + Se$$
$$b = Sf$$

gives you

$$f = \frac{b}{S}$$
$$e = \frac{a - T\frac{b}{S}}{S}$$
$$d = S$$
$$c = T$$

for any real numbers $S, T$.

Comment: The only point I don't quite see is that $c$, $d$, $e$ and $f$ must be natural numbers, and your solution will provide combinations of real numbers. Is there a way to constraint this? Or we should simply say that the solutions we're looking for are those where the four values result to be natural numbers.

Comment: Going that way, $d$ shall be restricted to be the product of some divisors of $b$ and $f$ of the remaining. Then $xf+yd=a$ shall be constrained to have positive solutions: not an easy job.